# Entire SVG scaling with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, graphics, svg, scale

I'm experimenting with the idea of making a web-based game with SVGs for graphics. I have one parent SVG element in my HTML file, and I dynamically insert SVGs loaded from other files with JavaScript. Internally, my game uses meters instead of pixels, and so pixel-wise, the graphics are quite large. Is there any way I can scale entire SVG elements? Or do I have to iterate through their graphical elements and scale them each individually?

In Google Chrome, explicitly setting currentScale doesn't seem to do anything; it's completely controlled by the browser's zoom level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set a `viewBox` attribute on the root svg element, that way you won't have to scale individual elements. Or leave them as is and allow zoom&pan. You can set a `viewBox` to show only part of the graphic too.

Without an example of how you use `currentScale` it's impossible to say if it's used correctly, but it should zoom the svg.